# Vba comparing then copying two different Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I realize there are a few different similar ideas on here. But I need help with this simple compare function.

My goal is to compare two different cells and if they are the same, replace it with its full non-abbreviated name.

Thank you for your time!!!

I.E

```
Sheet1           Sheet2
Column H    Column A   Column B
Dept        Dept       Department
```

This is what I have (Yes simple), but the cell H is not updating to the non-abbreviation:

```
 Sub updateDeptNames()

'Format user ID from the email column
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim tmpArray() As String, tempDept As String
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Student_Travel_DB") '--> This is the relevant sheet
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("gokoutd") '--> This is the relevant sheet

    LastRow = 1000 ''Bug finding the last row, had to hard code it

    For i = 2 To LastRow 'Iterate through all the rows in the sheet
       For j = 2 To 112
        tempDept = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value
        If ws.Range("H" & i).Value = tempDept Then
            ws.Range("H" & i) = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value
        End If
        Next j
    Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range("H" & i).value = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value` ?

Comment: That was just me trying to figure out the problem. I got it working though thx for your time though!

Answer (score 1):

You can more easily use `VLOOKUP` either on your worksheet or with VBA:

```
Sub GetFullName()
    Dim cl As Range, data As Range, lookUpRng As Range

    Set data = Worksheets("Student_Travel_DB").Range("A1:A10")
    Set lookUpRng = Worksheets("gokoutd").Range("A1:B10")

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cl In data
        cl = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, lookUpRng, 2, False)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

You'll need to change your range references.

Comment: Thx for the info. I got mine working. Im learning as I go so I realize mine wasnt optimal. but thank you for your time!